# CrossValidation using glmnet and very high values of Lambda?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, cross-validation

I am trying to run crossvalidation (folds=10) using glmnet library on my dataset. My outcome of interest is BMI and predictors include a set of clinical variables. My final goal is to use elastic-net regression to select features and also predict BMI. For crossvalidation, I am using a range of alpha from 0 to 1 using a 0.1 increment. I am using min CVM to decide the values of lambda, with my current code I get extremely high estimates for lambda. Are higher values of lambda acceptable or I am failing to see here? Below is my code snippet.  I appreciate all your help and comments.

```
size <- floor(nrow(DataFile) * 0.7)
Train_rows <- sample(rownames(DataFile),size=size,replace=FALSE)
Train_Data <- DataFile[Train_rows,]
Train_bmi <- phenoFile[Train_rows,]$BMI

####### Cross Validation Alpha and Lambda #####

myAlpha <-  seq(0,1,by=0.1)


findAlpha_lambda <- function(iAlpha){
   Train_Data <- as.matrix(Train_Data)
   crossModel <- cv.glmnet(Train_Data,Train_bmi,alpha=iAlpha)
   myLambda <- crossModel$lambda.min
   myCVM <- min(crossModel$cvm)
   title <- paste(iAlpha,myLambda,sep="_")
   return(c(iAlpha,myLambda,myCVM))
}

myFrame <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(myAlpha,findAlpha_lambda)))
colnames(myFrame) <- c('Alpha','Lamda','CVM')
myFrame <- myFrame[order(myFrame$CVM),]
print(myFrame)


     Alpha      Lamda      CVM
1    0.0 50.9839208 54.25337
2    0.1  1.7901432 54.37151
3    0.2  3.1427680 54.75240
4    0.3  2.1949422 57.68935
5    0.4  1.8927376 61.68384
9    0.8  1.2510439 63.69622
6    0.5  1.0933677 64.68333
8    0.7  0.2441112 64.73192
7    0.6  2.2050751 65.01727
11   1.0  1.3860429 65.17181
10   0.9  0.5042962 65.70732
```

Comment: P.S. I guess you did not standardize your data? If you do so, lambda might be small(er).

Comment: I tried both ways. I standardized the data using scale(Data,scale=T,center=F). The estimates didn't really differ much.  I updated the size to 0.75 and the lambda went down significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don‘t think a large lambda is a problem per se. It just means that a lot of regularization is going on (under Ridge). See here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212056/ridge-lasso-lambda-greater-than-1

Here is a good tutorial from the authors of `glmnet`. I suggest you check your approach, i.e by looking at various figures as shown in the tutorial, especially `plot(cvfit)` might be instructive. Also when you go through the tutorial, you see quite „large“ values of lambda (note that log of lambda is plotted).

https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html